# Separating socket.io logic from server file and accessing io.sockets in logic file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In `server.js` (starting point) of my Nodejs app, I do the following to start the server and the socket :

```
var socket = require('./routes/socket');

var port = process.env.PORT || 9091;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server is listening on port: ' + port);
}));

io.sockets.on('connection', socket);
```

Now in `./routes/socket` I want to be able to broadcast to all clients , which I believe I have to do it like this : `io.sockets.emit()` with the same `io`

The problem is that I don't have access to `io` in that file:

```
// export function for listening to the socket
var store = (function(){
    var value = 0;
    var getValue = function() {
        return value;
    };
    var addValue = function(toAdd) {
        value += toAdd.messages;
        return value;
    };
    return {
        getValue: getValue,
        addValue: addValue
    };
}());

module.exports = function (socket, io) {
    socket.emit('value', {
        value: store.getValue()
    });
    // broadcast a user's message to other users
    socket.on('getValue', function (data) {
        socket.emit('value', {
            value: store.getValue()
        });
    });

    socket.on('addValue', function (data) {
        store.addValue(data);
        io.sockets.emit('value', {
            value: store.getValue()
        });
    });
};
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `server.js` file at the end, it should be:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (sock) {
    socket(sock, io);
});
```